# How to call the knockout.js event from the keyDown event

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, keydown, keyevent

I want to execute the event bound by knockoutjs from the keyDown event.

Html

```
<button id="copyButton" data-bind="click: clipboardModel.copy">copy</button>
```

jQuery

```
$('#someElement').on('keydown', function(e) {
    switch (e.keyCode) {
        case 67: // c
            if (!(e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey)) break;
            $('#copyButton').click();
            break;
    }
});
```

It works with this, but  not seems to be the right way.

Comment: just a detail, but why "switch case" if you only have one case? I hope you've copied just a part of your switch case to simplify the question

Comment: @paulo.bing There are more conditions in the actual code.
I already got an answer close to the question sentence, so I think that it is better not to simplify it.
how is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [bind to the event directly](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/event-binding.html):

```
<input id="someElement" data-bind="event: { keydown: clipboardModel.copyKeydown }" />
```

Though it does mean you'll need to put your `keyCode` check in the knockout function instead:

```
var clipboardModel = {
    copyKeydown: function(data, e) {
        switch (e.keyCode) {
            case 67: // c
                if (!(e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey)) break;
                clipboardModel.copy();
                break;
        }
    },
    copy: function() { /*...*/ }
}
```

I've made some assumptions to your viewmodel here, you may need to adapt this slightly.

Comment: Thank you for answering. It's so pretty simple. I will give it a try.